# How to create an entry using php

Tags: entries

I am trying to create an entry using an API call, please help me or you can suggest me an add-on. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to better answer your question, it is helpful always to give some information about the environment you are working with - which version of EE, which version of php etc.

As for your question, to give you a better answer you would do well to clarify what you are trying to do:

- In general terms EE encourages developers to use Add-ons to hold code that executes php; there is good documentation on how to go about building and deploying add-ons in the [EE documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/plugins.html).
- It is possible to do some things using inline php similar to Wordpress, but to do this you need to enable php processing for your template (it is disabled by default) - more information on how to do this [in the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/overview.html#php-in-templates)
- As for how to create an entry, there is a worked example [in the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/models/channel-entry.html#create-a-new-simple-entry)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give more detail about what you're looking to as, as was rightly pointed out...

But in general there are Modules to help with this.

If you're looking to integrate the site with an API you should look at DataGrab... it's great for this kind of thing.

[DataGrab](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/datagrab)

Answer (score 0):

Reinos Webservice might be helpful as well. It supports an Entry API with support for third party addons